# Setup a Big Query Alert when no table row update/upload takes place

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

what's the best way to set up a Big Query alert per Email when no data was uploaded to a Big Query table for longer than one day? What comes to my mind is:

- Stackdriver
- Pub Sub
- Cloud Function

But I am not sure whats the fastest and best way to do so. I tried to set up via Stackdirver -> Create New Alert Ploicy

- Resource type:BigQuery Dataset
- Metric:Uploaded rows
- **Condition triggers if** -> Any time series violates -> **is absent FOR** 23 hours

But no Email was send. Although some tables get no data for months...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should create Audit Log Based Alert. Go to Logging -> Select BigQuery and then filter by inserts and you can create a log based metric and you can setup an alert rule based on that:

> To create an alerting policy on a logs-based counter metric, do the following:
>
> 1. Go to Logs-based metrics in the Google Cloud Console:
> 2. Find the metric you want to explore and select Create alert from
>      metric in the metric's More more_vert menu.
> 3. The Conditions pane opens, with the logs-based metric you chose
>      pre-populated in the Target dialog.
> 4. In the Configuration dialog, fill in the Threshold value.
> 5. Click Save, which displays the Create new alerting policy panel with
>      your completed condition.
> 6. Optional: Fill in the Notifications and Documentation sections.
> 7. In the Name this policy section, enter a name for the alerting
>      policy.
> 8. Click Save.

As mentioned on this page: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts

see this video which explains this in detail with a similar example about how to do this:
https://youtu.be/dqoZEfJ7UbM?t=1275